# VS 2013 Designer - "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Amongst other items, my solution contains a project that defines a control and another project that uses this control on a form. When I try to open this form in the VS Designer, I get the following error:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'libX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

where `libX` is neither the project with control, nor the project with the form. When I try to just build the solution, everything goes absolutely fine. When I run an application that shows the form, all is good. It's the Designer that seems to dislike something.

Things that I have tried so far:

- Having googled the issue, I have gone through the common attempts to solve this. Namely, the config of my solution is correct in the Configuration Manager and the project does not use anything of IIS (hence the solution with enabling 32b does not apply)
- I tried opening the form at work on a different version of VS 2013 (12.0.21005.1 REL) and that worked without any problems.
- I am using VS 2013 Update 5. Since there were times when the Designed worked OK, I tried downgrading to Update 2 - without help.
- I tried Repairing my VS - without help.

**EDIT:**
 A minimal project that demonstrates the problem is to be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk2x4xnc0r5ldga/so%2040052301.rar?dl=0). The problematic form is to be found in the `+lib.trading\lib.trading.obj.forms.strategyParametersForm` project.

The error that I get when opening the form in VS Designer is tnhe following:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: Is libX a project that is *used* by the control project or the form project? And is libX only 64-bit? If so, I suspect it's that VS is still trying to *run* the code in 32 bit mode, because it needs to run some of your user code while showing the designer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you for a response. Yes, libX is a project referenced by the control project and thus transitively by the form project as well. The current setting is that all projects are compiled as x86 and the problem is still on.

Comment: You need to use the [DesignMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code.  So that you won't attempt to use this library while your control(s) run in design mode.  Beyond it being a very bad idea in general, it can't work because you always run in 32-bit mode while in design mode.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for a response too. Could you please elaborate on what exactly is a very bad idea in general? I did what you suggested. The problem now changed - instead of "Cannot load `libX`" I get a "Cannot load `libY`" where `libY` is the project in which the `isInDesignMode()` extension of the Control class resides. Like I said, I find it weird that in a different version of VS everything works. On top of it, when I open JUST the control in VS Designer, it is displayed as well without any problems.

Comment: Well, problem solved by the sound of it, on to the next one.  Why you'd consider an extension method when you can simply use `this.DesignMode` is not very obvious.  You probably only have to build the project so liby.dll exists.  You are not helping us to help you, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HansPassant: Hans, I apologize - the MCVE has been added to the question. Naturally, `libY.dll` is compiled, that is not the problem. I used an extension method due to http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/447319/Resolve-DesignMode-for-a-user-control

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with my VS 2013, the form opens fine. It could be due to a VS 3rd party installed on your machine. (VS is a super hostile environment/IDE where every buggy dll can cause weird errors ...). I suggest you investigate further using fuslogvw https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx or reset your VS setup using command line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue with both VS 2013 and 2015. I had a similar issue in the past and it was related to the Excel Interop DLL used which was 64 bits but the application was x86. I don't know how Excel Interop is used in your library but maybe it will help.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue as well. I don't see a libX project in there so I assume you withheld for privacy reasons. A few things to try. Clean the solution. Rebuild and open the form. Does it work? Switch to AnyCPU, clean solution, compile and try to open the form again. Does it work? Check the .NET version you are targeting in each project. There is a chance you have different versions going on.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Simon, thanks for new information. I removed all 3rd party extensions/plugins and the problem still persists. When I launch ; `fuslogvw` it is empty even though I have turned dll binding error logging on. There is however some new info displayed on the control when I try to load the form, shown in the edit.

Comment: @OzanGunceler: Ozan, thank you. The solution does not use Excel Interop and other projects that I have on my computer that use Excel Interop, show forms all right, so it seems like an unlikely culprit

Comment: @Juan: Juan, thanks. All projects are using framework v4.0. I tried cleaning and rebuilding many times, to no effect. Changing to AnyCpu has no effect as well. I guess I have to create a fresh install of Win+VS.

Comment: I just remembered something else. Do you have the library registered in your local machine by any chance? Check to make sure that the one you are using to build your project is set to copy locally. Otherwise it will pick up from the GAC and that version may not match your current build configuration.

Comment: @Juan: Thanks for the idea - to be sure, I checked the GAC and the library is not there (as expected, I have not registered it so I would be surprised to find it there)

Comment: Did you check both GACs, 32 bit and 64 bit? I have been bitten in the past because the assembly was sitting in one GAC and not the other...

Comment: @Juan: Yes, I checked both.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. In case the application is run in Visual Studio installed on 64-bit OS with the TargetCPU = “Any CPU” the error message “An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000В)” can occur.

Comment: Thanks, but the error gets there regardless of AnyCpu, x86 or x64.

Comment: There is no particular error code, just an exception when I try to run the Designer. I edited the question to include the exception messageBox.